# Will SQLite database really remain intact if the program is forcibly terminated when changing the database?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, transactions

The SQLite documentation [says it is transactional](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html).

The explanation in the linked article states that if a C++ program which has the SQLite C++ code statically linked into it is forcibly terminated (for example, TerminateProcess() in WinAPI) or crashes when a write is being performed the database remains intact - either fully updated or fully unchanged.

Has anyone actually seen this reliably working? Does this work unconditionally or does it require any additional measures to be taken?

Answer (score 4):

As there is no totally secure way to do atomic transactions there is always the chance to have a corrupted state.

SQLite however takes special care when commiting and should leave the database intact even when the program crashes. It's saver than using flat files and the write-truncate-rename cycle which was the problem in the recent discussion about ext4.

See [Atomic Commit](http://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) for reference on how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on your journal mode.  If you are journalling to a file and the database does become corrupted there is a good chance it can be recovered.